# Swift `replaceSubrange` multiple substrings

Tags: swift, string, substring, swift3, string-matching

I am working on creating a HTML parser in Swift. It is very basic so all it does is simply take in a string of HTML, parse it for a given keyword, and highlight each occurrence of the keyword using HTML. It simply saves this string for a later user.

I have a loop that iterates over my HTML looking for occurrences of a given keyword and it returns all indexes where the keyword is found. Next, it then checks to make sure that the keyword is not part of a tag and is text between two tags. It then attempts to highlight each keyword.

The problem is, once I "highlight" a keyword by adding HTML around it it then changes the indices of the string, causing the next "highlight" to not highlight the keyword, but rather something else. Somehow I need each highlight to happen and be saved separate from the main string and then once every word is highlighted  concatenate them together. I'm not quite sure how to do this though. Can anybody help? Here is my code:

**Note**: The **highlight()** function is where I need help. The commented out code currently highlights one keyword given 1 index but any future keywords would be messed up because the indices would change.

```
import Foundation

private var html = ""
private let openTag = "<"
private let closeTag = ">"

extension String {
    func indicesOf(string: String) -> [Int] {
        var indices = [Int]()
        var searchStartIndex = self.startIndex

        while searchStartIndex < self.endIndex,
            let range = self.range(of: string, range: searchStartIndex..<self.endIndex),
            !range.isEmpty
        {
            let index = distance(from: self.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
            indices.append(index)
            searchStartIndex = range.upperBound
        }

        return indices
    }
}

func isTag(index : Int) -> Bool {
    let characters = Array(html.characters)
    for i in (0..<index).reversed() {
        if (String(characters[i]) == "<") {         // Open tag, ouch!
            return true
        } else if (String(characters[i]) == ">") {  // Closing tag, yippee!
            break
        }
    }
    for i in (index..<characters.count) {
        if (String(characters[i]) == "<") {         // Open tag, yippee!
            break
        } else if (String(characters[i]) == ">") {  // Closing tag, ouch!
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func highlight(indices : [Int], length : Int) {
    /*
    let highlight = "<span style=\"background-color: blue; color: white\">" + keyword + "</span>"
    html.replaceSubrange(html.index(html.startIndex, offsetBy: index) ..< html.index(html.startIndex, offsetBy: (index + keyword.characters.count)), with: highlight)
    print(html)
    */

    // indices = [0, 57, 75, 99, 104], length = "hello".count, so 5

    print(indices)
}

func parseHTML(keyword : String) {
    if (html.lowercased().contains(keyword.lowercased())) {     // Found it!
        let indices = html.indicesOf(string : keyword)          // Get all of the occurrences
        var validIndices = [Int]()
        for i in (0..<indices.count) {
            if (!isTag(index : indices[i])) {                   // Not a tag, let's do it!
                validIndices.append(indices[i])
            }
        }

        highlight(indices : validIndices, length : keyword.characters.count)
    }
}

let keyword = "hello"
html = "hello<hellohtmlhello><head><title>My Website</hellotitle>hello</head><body>hello</body></htmlhello>hellohello"
parseHTML(keyword: keyword);
```

Comment: What would be wrong with adding to your indices the length of the text you've added?

Comment: The keyword is the same for all so the length is always the same too. Unless I'm not understanding you correctly? Each indice is the index of the first character in the particular keyword's location in the HTML.

Comment: Update the indices with the length of the text you're *adding*. This seems an awful lot like homework.  Is it?  If so you can do it, just sit down and think about it a bit. Say you add some text at the first index.  How does that affect the overall length of the text you were searching in?  How does that affect the indices of the found elements?

Comment: Wow thank you. I am way too tired. I'm going on 11 straight hours for this homework. Is that sad? Lol.

Comment: If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Thank you, but it would be better to delete the question as an actual solution might have several different but valid answers. As currently asked your question is a bit too broad.  Rather than voting to close I was hoping to give you a nudge in the right direction.